# UICollectionViewCell move to next row when exceed UICollectionView width

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit

I wanted to make indefinite `UICollectionViewCell` that moves to another row once it's exceed the width of my `UICollectionView`. Here's the picture of what I'm trying to achieve.

[image]

As you can see, each width of the cell is resizing based on the content inside. The next cell will go horizontally, then after that it create another row if it exceed the width.

Here's my `UICollectionView`:

```
    var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
    let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    collectionView.backgroundColor = .white
    collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    collectionView.backgroundColor = MSColorFoundation.msClear
    return collectionView
}()
```

Here's my UICollectionViewLayoutDelegate:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let noOfCellsInRow = 3

    let flowLayout = collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout

    let totalSpace = (flowLayout?.sectionInset.left ?? 0.0)
    + (flowLayout?.sectionInset.right ?? 0.0)
    + ((flowLayout?.minimumInteritemSpacing ?? 0.0) * CGFloat(noOfCellsInRow - 1))

    let size = Int((collectionView.bounds.width - totalSpace) / CGFloat(noOfCellsInRow))

    return CGSize(width: size, height: 60)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to implement a UICollectionView with cells that flow from left to right, wrapping to the next row when they exceed the width of the collection view. This can be achieved using the UICollectionViewFlowLayout, which is a built-in layout class provided by UIKit.

To create a UICollectionViewFlowLayout that flows cells from left to right and wraps to the next row, you can set the scroll direction to horizontal and adjust the minimumInteritemSpacing and minimumLineSpacing properties as needed.

```
class MyCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {
    // Set up the collection view flow layout
    let flowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Configure the flow layout
        flowLayout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 10
        flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 10
        collectionView.collectionViewLayout = flowLayout

        // Register your custom UICollectionViewCell subclass
        collectionView.register(MyCustomCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "MyCustomCell")
        }

        // Implement the UICollectionViewDataSource methods to provide the data for your cells
        override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
            return 1
        }

        override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // Return the number of items in your data source
        return myData.count
        }

        override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "MyCustomCell", for: indexPath) as! MyCustomCell

            // Configure the cell with data from your data source
            cell.configure(with: myData[indexPath.item])

            return cell
        }
    }
```

In your custom UICollectionViewCell subclass, you can set the autoresizingMask property to allow the cell to resize itself as needed when the collection view width changes

```
class MyCustomCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    let label = UILabel()

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    // Set up the cell's subviews
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    contentView.addSubview(label)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor),
        label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor),
        label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor),
        label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor)
    ])

    // Configure the label's appearance
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.textColor = .white
    label.backgroundColor = .blue
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

func configure(with text: String) {
    label.text = text
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    // Allow the cell to resize itself as needed when the collection view width changes
    contentView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth]
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see in your code, the `sizeForItemAt` function will always create cells in a way that your collection view will always have 3 cells in a row. I would suggest you to omit your `sizeForItemAt` function and create a simple Xib cell. Take a label in you Xib and then give your label a leading and trailing constant then register that Xib to your collection view. This will make your every cell to automatically depend on its label and infer its width from its label.